# how to change all bookmarks property to inherit zoom in existing pdf using itext

Tags: java, itext

This code change all property of root bookmark to inheritzoom.
But i want to access Kids array of bookmarks and all bookmarks to inherit zoom.
how i access Kids array of bookmarks?
i want to change only property of bookmarks not destinations.
how i achieve? Can anyone help me out from this.

```
List<HashMap<String,Object>> list = SimpleBookmark.getBookmark(reader);
for(HashMap<String, Object> lis:list)
{
System.out.println(lis.size());
lis.put("Page",String.format("%d %s",page++,"XYZ"));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to access the Kids of a bookmark. This is done like this:

```
list.get("Kids");
```

Comment: Till this i reached and i printed it on console. Actually it stores in arraylist[key,value] and using hashmap(key)-> another(k,v). How i access internal elements?